# How to set AWS S3 Policy where Principals is all principals in a specific aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

It seems the following is an invalid principal for a Deny statement:

```
"Principal" : {
    "AWS" : [
      "arn:aws:iam::123412341234:*"
    ]
  }
```

Assuming 123412341234 is our account id.

How to set this?  It seems below could work, but means having to list all relevant arns from external accounts explicitly:

```
  "NotPrincipal" : {
    "AWS" : [
      "arn:aws:iam::111112341234:role/blar1",
      "arn:aws:iam::111112341234:role/blar2",
      "arn:aws:iam::111112341234:root",
      "arn:aws:iam::555552341234:role/blar3",
      "arn:aws:iam::555552341234:root",
    ]
  }
```

In fact according to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/ this won't even work because I have to include `assumed-role` arns which cannot be known ahead of time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html

Comment: What is your actual use-case? Are you granting public access to _Anyone_, but then wanting to exclude a particular account (eg a test, or prod account)? How are they being granted access in the first place, thus requiring a Deny?

Comment: We want to Deny all by default, but we don't want to Deny external accounts that need access to our s3 buckets.  We cannot know their ARNs (or aws:userIds) without explicit permission to lookup, so the AWS documentation seems to imply it's not possible.  As in I'll just have to ask external accounts to let me know their AROA style aws:userIds for the roles they need access to our s3 buckets.

Comment: So you want to allow anybody's account to access the bucket (making it a public bucket), but you don't want your own account to be able to access it? I'm confused.

Comment: We don't want to allow external accounts access to the bucket, rather we want to exclude external accounts from an explicit Deny.  It's not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you have the `Deny`? Are you granting people access to "All buckets", but you want this bucket to be an exception? Is it a highly-sensitive bucket? Could you simply not grant Allow access in the first place, thereby removing the need for a Deny? More information, please!

Answer (score 0):

Seems this works:

```
"Principal" : {
  "AWS" : [
    "*"
  ]
}
"Condition" : {
    "ArnLike" : {
      "aws:PrincipalArn" : [
        "arn:aws:iam::123412341234:*"
      ]
    }
  }
```